# Text wont unselect on web page in Microsoft Edge on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: chromium

I often like to read certain text on the web by selecting it as I read or just to select and copy, but I have recently been noticing after I do this that anywhere else I click on the page does not then perform the expected deselect or unselect.
Does anyone know why this might be? I'm not sure if it's something due to ubuntu, my computer or Microsoft Edge on ubuntu.
I have ubuntu desktop 22.04.02 and microsoft-edge-stable 110.0.1587.63-1

Comment: You could test, and if it works as expected in, say, Firefox, then it should be safe to exclude Ubuntu and "my computer", and blame it on the last option.

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue to be pretty annoying, I discovered that disabling the mini context menu fixes this problem.

See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71649638/prevent-context-menu-in-edge-when-text-is-selected